# SQLite DB wrong name column when create table

Tags: java, android, sqlite

in android to create the table Movie and manage it, i have written this code:

**MovieDatabase.java**

```
package com.example.msnma.movienotifier.database;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.MainActivity;
import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.databaseModel.MovieDBModel;
import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.databaseModel.TypeDBModel;
import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.mapper.MovieMapper;
import com.example.msnma.movienotifier.model.Movie;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MovieDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "movieDatabase";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_MOVIE = "MovieTable";
    private static final String TABLE_TYPE = "TypeTable";
    private static final String TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE = "MovieTypeTable";
    //Table Fields
    private static final String MOVIE_ID ="movie_id";
    private static final String TITLE ="title";
    private static final String OVERVIEW = "overview";
    private static final String POSTER_URL = "posterUrl";
    private static final String BACKDROP_URL = "backdropUrl";
    private static final String TRAILER_URL = "trailerUrl";
    private static final String RELEASE_DATE = "releaseDate";
    private static final String RATING = "rating";
    private static final String ADULT = "adult";

    private static final String TYPE_ID = "type_id";
    private static final String TYPE_DESCR = "type_descr";

    private static final String MOVIE_TYPE_ID = "movie_type_id";
    private static final String M_ID = "movie_id";
    private static final String T_ID = "type_id";
    private static final String notify_datetime = "notify_datetime";

    // Table Create Statements
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_MOVIE + "(" + MOVIE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + OVERVIEW + " TEXT," + POSTER_URL + " TEXT," + BACKDROP_URL + " TEXT," + TRAILER_URL + " TEXT,"
            + RATING + " REAL," + ADULT + " INTEGER," + RELEASE_DATE + " DATETIME," + notify_datetime + " DATETIME"  + ")";

    // Tag table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_TYPE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_TYPE
            + "(" + TYPE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + TYPE_DESCR + " TEXT" + ")";

    // todo_tag table create statement
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE + "(" + MOVIE_TYPE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + M_ID + " INTEGER," + T_ID + " INTEGER" + ")";

    SQLiteDatabase database;

    public MovieDatabase(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        database = getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // creating required tables
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TYPE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE);
        insertType(db); //NOTA: questo va chiamato solo la prima volta che instanziamo il DB, AGGIUNGERE CONTROLLO!
        //in teoria onCreate verrà chiamato solo la prima volta...
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        // on upgrade drop older tables
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MOVIE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TYPE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE);

        // create new tables
        onCreate(db);
    }
    //questa funzione serve solo per inserire casualmente dai suggested movies, alcuni notify e watched movies
    public static void saveMoviesOnDB(List<Movie> movies, String type){
        MovieDatabase db = MainActivity.getMovieDatabase();
        MovieMapper mapper = new MovieMapper();
        List<MovieDBModel> moviesDB = mapper.toMovieDBModelList(movies);
        Integer typeId = 0;
        int index = 0;
        if(type.equals("notify")){
            typeId = 1;
        }else if(type.equals("watched")){
            typeId = 2;
            index = index+5;
        }else{
            //todo catch invalid type Id exception
        }
        for(int a = index; a<index+5; a++){
            insertMovie(moviesDB.get(a), typeId, db);
        }
    }
    //open the database, maybe not useful...
    public MovieDatabase open() throws SQLException
    {
        database = getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    // closing database
    public void closeDB() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        if (db != null && db.isOpen())
            db.close();
    }

    //CRUDs
    public static void insertMovie(MovieDBModel movie, Integer typeId, MovieDatabase db) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = db.getWritableDatabase();
        if(checkMovieUniqueness(movie.getTitle(), db)) {        //NON VOGLIO INSERIRE PIù VOLTE LO STESSO FILM
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(TITLE, movie.getTitle());
            values.put(OVERVIEW, movie.getOverview());
            values.put(POSTER_URL, movie.getPosterUrl());
            values.put(BACKDROP_URL, movie.getBackdropUrl());
            values.put(TRAILER_URL, movie.getTrailerUrl());
            values.put(RELEASE_DATE, movie.getReleaseDate().toString());
            values.put(RATING, movie.getRating());
            values.put(ADULT, movie.isAdult());
            //inizio nuovo codice
            if(typeId == 1) {
                values.put(notify_datetime, movie.getNotifyDate().toString());
                Log.i("TYPEID", "Siamo dentro");
            }
            //else values.putNull(NOTIFY_TIME_DATE);
            //fine nuovo codice
            // insert row
            long movieId = database.insert(TABLE_MOVIE, null, values);
            insertMovieType(movieId, typeId, db);
        }
    }

    public static void insertMovieType(Long movieId, Integer typeId, MovieDatabase db){
        SQLiteDatabase database = db.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(M_ID, movieId.intValue());
        values.put(T_ID, typeId);

        database.insert(TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE, null, values);
    }

    private void insertType(SQLiteDatabase db){

        ContentValues descr1 = new ContentValues();
        descr1.put(TYPE_DESCR, "NOTIFY");

        ContentValues descr2 = new ContentValues();
        descr2.put(TYPE_DESCR, "WATCHED");

        // insert row
        db.insert(TABLE_TYPE, null, descr1);
        db.insert(TABLE_TYPE, null, descr2);
    }

    private TypeDBModel getTypeByTypeDescr(String typeDescr) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TYPE + " WHERE "
                + TYPE_DESCR + " = " + typeDescr;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if (c != null)
            c.moveToFirst();

        TypeDBModel td = new TypeDBModel();
        td.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(TYPE_ID)));
        td.setDescription((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TYPE_DESCR))));

        return td;
    }

    private static boolean checkMovieUniqueness(String movieTitle, MovieDatabase db) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = db.getReadableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIE + " WHERE "
                + TITLE + " = " + "'"+ movieTitle + "'";

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            c.close();
            return false;
        }else{
            c.close();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public List<MovieDBModel> getAllMovieByType(String typeDescr) throws ParseException {
        List<MovieDBModel> movies = new ArrayList<MovieDBModel>();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_MOVIE + " mv, "
                + TABLE_TYPE + " type, " + TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE + " tmt WHERE type."
                + TYPE_DESCR + " = '" + typeDescr + "'" + " AND type." + TYPE_ID
                + " = " + "tmt." + T_ID + " AND mv." + MOVIE_ID + " = "
                + "tmt." + M_ID;

        Log.e(LOG, selectQuery);

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                MovieDBModel td = new MovieDBModel();
                td.setId(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(MOVIE_ID))));
                td.setTitle((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TITLE))));
                td.setOverview(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(OVERVIEW)));
                td.setPosterUrl(c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(POSTER_URL))));
                td.setBackdropUrl((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(BACKDROP_URL))));
                td.setTrailerUrl(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TRAILER_URL)));
                String dateString =c.getString((c.getColumnIndex(RELEASE_DATE)));
                Date date = sdf3.parse(dateString);
                td.setReleaseDate(date);
                td.setRating((c.getFloat(c.getColumnIndex(RATING))));
                int adult = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(ADULT));
                if(adult == 0){
                    td.setAdult(true);          //NOT sure if is the contrary
                }else{
                    td.setAdult(false);
                }

                movies.add(td);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        return movies;
    }

    public void deleteMovie(long tado_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_MOVIE, MOVIE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(tado_id) });
    }

    public void deleteMovieType(long tado_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE, M_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(tado_id) });
    }

    public int updateMovieType(long id, long tag_id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(T_ID, tag_id);

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_MOVIE_TYPE, values, M_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    }
}
```

Now when the app runs i have this error in the logs:

```
2018-08-27 23:08:02.336 3786-3786/com.example.msnma.movienotifier E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting rating=7.0 title=Crazy Rich Asians notify_datetime=Thu Sep 27 09:30:00 GMT+02:00 2018 posterUrl=https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/gnTqi4nhIi1eesT5uYMmhEPGNih.jpg releaseDate=Wed Aug 15 00:00:00 GMT+02:00 2018 adult=false trailerUrl=https://youtube.com/watch?v=PI5mBzQ1Iok overview=An American-born Chinese economics professor accompanies her boyfriend to Singapore for his best friend's wedding, only to get thrust into the lives of Asia's rich and famous. backdropUrl=https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300/zeHB7aP46Xs3u4aFLuAq2GFeUGb.jpg
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table MovieTable has no column named notify_datetime (Sqlite code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MovieTable(rating,title,notify_datetime,posterUrl,releaseDate,adult,trailerUrl,overview,backdropUrl) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?), (OS error - 2:No such file or directory)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:910)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:521)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:603)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:63)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1725)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1593)
        at com.example.msnma.movienotifier.database.MovieDatabase.insertMovie(MovieDatabase.java:151)
        at com.example.msnma.movienotifier.adapter.MoviesAdapter$7.onClick(MoviesAdapter.java:378)
        at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Indeed my last column is named *notify_datetimeDATETIME* instead of *notifify_datetime*

[Wrong name last column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVRsC.png)

It seems to concatenate two strings with `notify_datetime + " DATETIME"`

What can I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to remove app, rerun on device or increase `DATABASE_VERSION`. Because database cannot recreate when it exists.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't released the app you can simply change the name of the column and then do a fresh install.  Once you release the app however, you will have to increment your db version number then override `onUpgrade`.  In that method you can check if the old version is less than the newest version and modify the table accordingly, if the data can be lost, just drop and recreate the table, if it cannot be lost, use an alter table statement.

For example

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final int DATABASE_NAME = "myDb.sqlite";

private DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, SharedPrefsContract.Manager sharedPrefsManager) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion < 2) {
        // There is where you alter the table
    }
}
```

To alter the table

First you rename the old table:

```
ALTER TABLE orig_table_name RENAME TO tmp_table_name;
```

Then create the new table, based on the old table but with the updated column name:

```
CREATE TABLE orig_table_name (
  col_a INT
, col_b INT
);
```

Then copy the contents across from the original table.

```
INSERT INTO orig_table_name(col_a, col_b)
SELECT col_a, colb
FROM tmp_table_name;
```

Lastly, drop the old table.

```
DROP TABLE tmp_table_name;
```

Wrapping all this in a `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;` is also probably a good idea.